# How do I stop a script from running for one player but not all?

Tags: roblox

I am trying to make a script that once you click a gui it stops but I want the game to be multiplayer but once the gui is clicked it stops it for all player.

I tried "workspace.Det.Script.Enabled=false" hoping that it would only disable it for the player that clicked the gui

The script is in a gui with a button image and inside the script its says "

```
function onclick()
    workspace.Det.Death.Enabled=false
    workspace.Det.Script.Enabled=false
    workspace.Just.Death.Enabled=false
    workspace.Just.Script.Enabled=false
    workspace.Kind.Death.Enabled=false
    workspace.Kind.Script.Enabled=false
    game.StarterGui.Determination.Enabled=false
    game.StarterGui.Bravery.Enabled=false
    game.StarterGui.Justice.Enabled=false
    game.StarterGui.Kindness.Enabled=false
end

script.Parent.MouseButton1Click:connect(onclick)
```

"

Comment: please share some code for further analysis